# Cannot read property 'g' of undefined

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Using Fireabse Auth I get Cannot read property 'g' of undefined when trying to use any of the auth methods.  Twitter, Github, and Facebook all still manage to login even when they get this error, but Google won't. Inspecting things on the console lead me nowhere.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'g' of undefined
    at cW (base.js:3515)
    at AV.g.h.OJ (base.js:6673)
cW @ base.js:3515
g.h.OJ @ base.js:6673
```

Comment: Please provide some code to help reproduce this.